# words in my array duplicate for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have finally achieved to take off the empty strings (Thank you very much Mark), but I was busy with the check and I noticed it duplicates words in my array for no reason. Take a look at my JSON and then at the screenshot.

JSON:

```
{
"main_object": {
"id": "new",
"getExerciseTitle": "Let's go",
"language": "nl_NL",
"application": "lettergrepen",
"main_object": {
  "title": "Let's go",
  "language": "nl_NL",
  "exercises": [
    {
      "word": "huisartsenpraktijk",
      "syllables": [
        "huis",
        "artsen",
        "praktijk"
      ]
    },
    {
      "word": "Terschelling",
      "syllables": [
        "ter",
        "schelling"
      ]
    },
    {
      "word": "voetbalclub",
      "syllables": [
        "voet",
        "bal",
        "club"
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"dataType": "json"
}
}
```

Now take a look at the screenshot:

[image]

Notice how the words in my array are duplicating sometimes and therefore leaving empty input fields?

This is how I created the check to see whether the length equals the JSON length:

```
if (exercise.syllables.length === correctSylls.length) {
$(this).closest('.syll-row').find('input.syl-input').addClass('btn btn-success').removeClass('form-control').prop('disabled', true);
 }
```

And this is how the complete function looks like (I took the not related part out and just kept the related part).

```
       var correctSylls = [];

    $.map(exercise.syllables, function (syllable, j) { 
        var sylInput = $('<input/>', {
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control syl-input',
            'name':  +c++,
            'id': +idsyll++
        }).on('keyup', function() {
            var cValue = $(this).val();
            if (cValue === syllable) {
              correctSylls.push(cValue);
              console.log(correctSylls);
            }
            if (exercise.syllables.length === correctSylls.length) {
                $(this).closest('.syll-row').find('input.syl-input').addClass('btn btn-success').removeClass('form-control').prop('disabled', true);
            } 
        });
    });
    idsyll = 0;
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keyup` event will fire on every keystroke. If that's what you want, you should probably check whether the element already exists in the array and push it otherwise. Another option is to use the `change` event which will only fire once, or the `blur` event which will fire when the input loses focus.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why my words are duplicating or is that the reason? quick edit: Would it then be possible to use blur but when the right word is inserted for it to lose focus?

Comment: Yes. That might be the reason if you're matching multiple keystrokes against the same word. I can't tell from the small snippet you've provided though.

Comment: Tried blur, that works now. (it does NOT duplicate any words). so thumbs up for you and thank you very much